# utility method to check for null, undefined or empty

Tags: typescript

Is there any utility method out there in typescript, preferably lodash since I am already using it to check for `null|undefined|''|'<empty with white space>'`

I checked around a bit but could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use _.isNil(value).Refer this [Lodash isNil](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isNil)

Comment: Thanks, however I cannot use this to check for empty spaces like '  '.  On a side note what is the difference between just checking if (varName) vs _.isNil(varName) ?